# Getting an error with Acquia Dev Desktop

Tags: installation, acquia-dev-desktop

Upon setting up Drupal 8 through Acquia Dev Desktop, I get to the Choose Language screen fine but then when I get to Set Up Database and put in the Database Name and Database username/password, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The service definition "renderer" does not exist.' in C:\Users\Sites\devdesktop\drupal-newest\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\ContainerBuilder.php:796 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Sites\devdesktop\drupal-newest\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\ContainerBuilder.php(440): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition('renderer') #1 C:\Users\Sites\devdesktop\drupal-newest\core\lib\Drupal.php(158): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get('renderer') #2 C:\Users\Sites\devdesktop\drupal-newest\core\includes\install.core.inc(1151): Drupal::service('renderer') #3 C:\Users\Sites\devdesktop\drupal-newest\core\includes\install.core.inc(1089): install_database_errors(Array, './sites/drupal-...') #4 C:\Users\Sites\devdesktop\drupal-newest\core\includes\install.core.inc(366): install_verify_database_settings('sites/dr in C:\Users\E0217625\Sites\devdesktop\drupal-newest\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\ContainerBuilder.php on line 796

I have no idea what this means since I was having no problems before.
I've set up sites before with no issues but all of a sudden, I'm unable to create new sites.

Any help/direction on what I should do to create a new site would be great.

Comment: try installing D8 again. I've gotten that error as well. Seems like a random error.

Comment: I've tried to re-install a new one about 7-8 times already and keep getting this error now. @NoSssweat

Comment: did you empty/delete the database before each re-install?

Comment: I did. It seems to be a very random thing. Eventually got it working again.